# create json file with 3 properties

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create json file with 3 property on is key and for every key there is two fields, currently I try with the following and I got error,whatI miss here?

```
{
    "test1": {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "USER"
    }"Test2": {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "USER2"
    }
}
```

Comment: A comma here: `}, "Test2":`

Comment: and make sure all the property names follows the same notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comma to separate test1 array from test2 array

```
{
    "test1": {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "USER"
    },
    "test2": {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "USER2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is comma separated. After each key:value pair there must be a comma unless it is the last in the set e.g.

```
{ 
 "Item_1":{
    "Item_1_Param1": "Param1", // Comma required here
    "Item_1_Param2": "Param2"  // Comma not required here
 }, // Comma required here
  "Item_2":{
    "Item_2_Param1": "Param1", // Comma required here 
    "Item_2_Param2": "Param2"  // Comma not required here 
 }  // Comma not required here
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is ok, you just need to add a comma

```
{
"test1": {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "USER"
}
, // comma here is important
"Test2": {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "USER2"
}
}
```